# Paypal Lib : issue with orientation

Tags: ios4, paypal

I have integrated Paypal lib in my application. Ref : https://www.x.com/community/ppx/xspaces/mobile/mep

My application is in landscape mode, when give call to paypal,screen comes in portrait mode.

is there anyway to override this behavior.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having talk with Tech guy from PayPal,following is the response I got

The payment portion works only in portrait mode. This was a design decision to avoid undue scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

After I've come across that line in documentation of PayPal MPL, I thought it was impossible to show the checkbox view in landscape mode. Fortunately there is a way to do it manually. Thanks to my colleagues :)

The checkbox view is an instance of PayPalViewClass. Just add a method to look through all the views and all the subviews to find the instanse of this class. Once you've found the view you was looking for just apply setTransform method to it. The method should look like this:

```
-(void) cicle:(UIView*)v{ 
    for (UIView *_v in [v subviews]) {
       if ([_v isKindOfClass:[NSClassFromString(@"PayPalViewClass") class]]) {
         [v setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2)];
       }
       [self cicle:_v];
    }
}
```

It should be called in your payWithPayPal method. I hope this helps ;)