# PayPal view not displaying in Landscape mode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, paypal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Paypal Lib : issue with orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561929/paypal-lib-issue-with-orientation)

I have integrated PayPal library in my iPhone app. But when I tap the "pay with paypal" button for the sandbox enviornment, the PapPal view is displaying only in portrait mode.

Is there any way to display the PapPal view in landscape mode too ?

Comment: awsome question dude , thats y i gave upvote ... but i tried alot,i think no way to solve this issue.... let me know

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561929/paypal-lib-issue-with-orientation

Comment: this is a duplicate why does it get so many votes?

Answer (score 2):

The payment API ***only*** works in portrait mode. Unfortunately it was a design decision to avoid scrolling.

See Page 36 of the PayPal MPL Developer Guide.

[image]