# Is there any way to create a PayPal checkbox manually?

Tags: ios, checkbox, paypal, landscape

I have faced up with the problem with orientation of PayPal checkbox in my landscape application (portrait mode is not supported).

That's a quote from MPL Guide:
NOTE: The checkout experience is in Portrait orientation only. Landscape orientation is currently 
not supported.

I'm thinking of creating my own view to enter the PayPal login and password in order to avoid the problem. Is it posible to use PayPal MPL with a custom view?

Answer (score 0):

After I've come across that line in documentation of PayPal MPL, I thought it was impossible to show the checkbox view in landscape mode. Fortunately there is a way to do it manually. Thanks to my colleagues :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13057499/1689376